# limit map key and value types - more complicated

Tags: java, generics

I have a more complicated issue (than question 'Java map with values limited by key's type parameter' question) for mapping key and value type in a Map. Here it is:

```
interface AnnotatedFieldValidator<A extends Annotation> {
  void validate(Field f, A annotation, Object target);
  Class<A> getSupportedAnnotationClass();
}
```

Now, I want to store validators in a map, so that I can write the following method:

```
validate(Object o) {
  Field[] fields = getAllFields(o.getClass());
  for (Field field: fields) {
    for (Annotation a: field.getAnnotations()) {
      AnnotatedFieldValidator validator = validators.get(a);
      if (validator != null) {
        validator.validate(field, a, target);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(type parameters are omitted here, since I do not have the solution). I also want to be able to register my validators:

```
public void addValidator(AnnotatedFieldValidator<? extends Annotation> v) {
  validators.put(v.getSupportedAnnotatedClass(), v);
}
```

With this (only) public modifier method, I can ensure the map contains entries for which the key (annotation class) matches the validator's supported annotation class.

Here is a try:

I declare the validators Map like this:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, AnnotatedFieldValidator<? extends Annotation>> validators;
```

I'm aware I cannot properly link the key and value (link is assumed OK due to only access through `addValidator()`), so I tried a cast:

```
for (Annotation a: field.getAnnotations()) {
  AnnotatedFieldValidator<? extends Annotation> validator = validators.get(a);
  if (validator != null) {
    validator.validate(field, validator.getSupportedAnnotationClass().cast(a), target);
  }
}
```

But this does not work: `The method validate(Field, capture#8-of ?, Object) in the type AnnotatedFieldValidator<capture#8-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Field, capture#9-of ?, Object)`.

I can't figure out why this does not work: the `AnnotatedFieldValidator` has a single type parameter (A), which is used both as the return type of `getSupportedAnnotationClass()` and as a parameter of `validate()`; thus, when casting the annotation to supportedAnnotationClass, I should be able to pass it as the parameter to `validate()`. Why is the result of `getSupportedAnnotationClass()` considered a different type than the parameter of `validate()`?

I can solve the `validate()` method by removing wildcards in the validators declaration and `validate()` method, but then, of course, `addValidator()` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, it really helped me come to the following solution.

The answer from flicken showed me the way: I have to extract some code into a parameterized method. but instead of extracting `validators.get()` in a method, I can extract the whole validation process. Doing so, I can use programmatic cast (which I assume OK since I control the coherence of key to values map):

```
public void validate(Object o) {
  Field[] fields = getFields(o.getClass());
  for (Field field : fields) {
    Annotation[] annotations = field.getAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
      AnnotatedFieldValidator<? extends Annotation> validator = 
          validators.get(annotation.annotationType());
      if (validator != null) {
        doValidate(field, validator, annotation, o);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then, the doValidate() method is as follows:

```
private <A extends Annotation> void doValidate(Field field, 
      AnnotatedFieldValidator<A> validator, Annotation a, Object o) {
    // I assume this is correct following only access to validators Map
    // through addValidator()
    A annotation = validator.getSupportedAnnotationClass().cast(a);
    try {
        validator.validate(field, annotation, bean, beanName);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
}
```

No cast (OK, except Class.cast()...), no unchecked warnings, no raw type, I am happy.

Comment: You have turned an implicit cast (when using a raw type) into an explicit one. But I find this solution acceptable. I just don't have the reflex yet of pulling out another generic method out of my sleeve to do some typing magic.

Comment: Glad you found an acceptable solution.   I prefer extracting the getValidator method, because it encapsulates access to the validators Map.  However, yours looks more elegant at the top-level validate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a method to get the validator.  All access to the `validators` Map is through type-checked method, and are thus type-safe.

```
    protected <A extends Annotation> AnnotatedFieldValidator<A> getValidator(A a) {
        // unchecked cast, but isolated in method
        return (AnnotatedFieldValidator<A>) validators.get(a);
    }

    public void validate(Object o) {
        Object target = null;
        Field[] fields = getAllFields(o.getClass());
        for (Field field : fields) {
            for (Annotation a : field.getAnnotations()) {
                AnnotatedFieldValidator<Annotation> validator = getValidator(a);
                if (validator != null) {
                    validator.validate(field, a, target);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Generic map
    private Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, AnnotatedFieldValidator<? extends Annotation>> validators;
```

(Removed second suggestion as duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

Generics provide information which only exists at compile-time; at run-time all the information is lost.  When compiling code with generics, the compiler will strip out all the generic type information and insert casts as necessary.  For example,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test");
String s = list.get(0);
```

will end up being compiled as

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("test");
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

with the compiler automatically adding the cast in the third line.

It looks to me like you are trying to use generics for run-time type safety.  This is not possible.  In the line

```
validator.validate(field, a, target);
```

there is no way for the compiler to know what subtype of `Annotation` the validator expects.

I think the best thing to do is to drop the type variable `A` and declare your interface as follows:

```
interface AnnotatedFieldValidator {
  void validate(Field f, Annotation annotation, Object target);
  Class<? extends Annotation> getSupportedAnnotationClass();
}
```

`addValidator` would then also lose its parameterised type, i.e.

```
public void addValidator(AnnotatedFieldValidator v) {
  validators.put(v.getSupportedAnnotationClass(), v);
}
```

The downside of this is that you will have to check that your validators are being passed an annotation of a class that they can validate.  This is easiest to do in the code that calls the validator, e.g.

```
if (validator.getSupportedAnnotationClass().isInstance(a)) {
  validator.validate(field, a, target);
}
else {
  // wrong type of annotation, throw some exception.
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is no way for the compiler to know. This is why I have a method that enforces the coherence (addValidator()). Now that I assume coherence whith this, I should be able to call Class.cast(Object). Your solution still needs to cast the object, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Haa .. I think I figure it out :)

```
for (Annotation a: field.getAnnotations()) {
  AnnotatedFieldValidator<? extends Annotation> validator = validators.get(a);
  if (validator != null) {
    validator.validate(field, validator.getSupportedAnnotationClass().cast(a), target);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** (changed my viewpoint)

This semantic is correct when you look at it from a runtime perspective but not at **COMPILE TIME**.

Here the **compiler** assumes that `validator.getSupportedAnnotationClass().cast()` will give you a `Class<? extends Annotation>`.

and when you call:

```
validator.validate(field, validator.getSupportedAnnotationClass().cast(a), target);
```

the **compiler** expects a `Class<? extends Annotation>` as argument.

Here's the problem. From the compiler point-of-view, these types could be 2 different types at runtime although in this case the semantic doesn't allow this.

Comment: I disagree with you: when I call AnnotatedFieldValidator<Deprecated>.getSupportedAnnotationClass(), I get Class<Deprecated>. Therefore, cast() on this class should return an instance of Deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll give this a go, since generics are tricky material and I may learn something from the reactions. So, *please correct me if I'm wrong*.

First, let me put your source code in one block. (renamed `AnnotatedFieldValidator` into `AFV` for conciseness)

```
interface AFV<A extends Annotation>
{
  void validate(Field f, A annotation, Object target);
  Class<A> getSupportedAnnotationClass();
}

private Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, AFV<? extends Annotation>> validators;

public void validate(Object o) {
  Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  for (Field field: fields) {
    for (Annotation a: field.getAnnotations()) {
      AFV<? extends Annotation> validator = validators.get(a.getClass());
      if (validator != null) {
        validator.validate(field, a, o);
      }
    }
  }
}

public void addValidator(AFV<? extends Annotation> v) {
  validators.put(v.getSupportedAnnotationClass(), v);
}
```

The trouble is that when you iterate over the annotations of a field, the only type the compiler can deduce is `Annotation`, not a specialization of it. If you now pull the correct `AFV` from the `Map`, and you try to call `validate` on it, there is a type clash on the second parameter, since `AFV` wants to see the specific subclass of `Annotation` it is parameterized with, but only gets `Annotation`, which is too weak.

As you already said yourself, if the only way to add validators is through the `addValidator` method, then you can internally ensure type safety through it, and rewrite as follows:

```
interface AFV<A extends Annotation>
{
    void validate(Field f, A annotation, Object target);
    Class<A> getSupportedAnnotationClass();
}

private Map<Class<?>, AFV<?>> validators;

public void validate(Object o)
{
    Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields)
    {
        for (Annotation a : field.getAnnotations())
        {
            // raw type to keep compiler happy
            AFV validator = validators.get(a.getClass());
            if (validator != null)
            {
                validator.validate(field, a, o); // statically unsafe
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addValidator(AFV<?> v)
{
    validators.put(v.getSupportedAnnotationClass(), v);
}
```

Note that the call `validator.validate` is now statically unsafe, and the compiler will issue a warning. But if you can live with that, this might do.

Comment: I must agree I'm a bit "extremist", but I would prefer a solution without raw type.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. There is simply insufficient type information available, and casting will be necessary if you have a parameterized AFV. Generics here are simply used to "autocast" behind the scenes. Drop generics and you will have to do a type check yourself with Class.isInstance for example.